# Xcode 11 - Removing localization

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I am trying to remove languages that are not supported in our app. In the project file in the info tab, I have removed all the languages under the Localizations. 
Then I build the app and launch on my iPhone that is on iOS 13. In the System Settings, I find my app name and I can see Languages. When I click on it I can see the languages that are not supported anymore. Is there any other place I should remove something in order not to see those languages?

Comment: If you are using Xib or Storyboard, click on the file, and you'll see at the trailing side of Xcode the ```LOCALIZATION``` section. Uncheck those unsupported languages.

Comment: 99% of the UI is done in code. XIBs are not localized, the text is updated by using the code.

Comment: Can you try to remove the app from the phone itself and reboot it.  Then re-deploy the app.  I have found some resources-related files are not noticed when you deploy an app which is already on the phone (it is a kind of short-cut install instead of a clean install).

Comment: I have a branch that I am currently fixing translations on. When I switch to another branch and return back all the languages I have deleted in Project/localizations are back again. After deleting them again my GIT shows changes in the file that is usually in gitignore /Users/MY_USER/code/PROJECT_FOLDER/PROJECT_NAME.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/MY_USER.xcuserdatad

Answer (score 0):

I found that erasing the simulator device and deleting the .lproj subdirectory wasn't enough, the deleted language was still showing up in the app settings. But restarting Xcode and cleaning the build folder seemed to do the trick.